# Keycloak, Tomcat 9, and @RolesAllowed?

Tags: security, tomcat, authorization, keycloak, tomcat9

I am trying to configure my Tomcat 9-based web application to leverage Keycloak for its security provider.  I've done this in the past on Wildfly with no problem using the Wildfly adapter.  I'm running into issues doing this in Tomcat 9, though.  Here's what I've done...

I've added the Keycloak Tomcat adapter to my project using maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-tomcat8-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In my `context.xml` file I've defined the Keycloak authenticator valve:

```
<Context path="/myapp">
    <Valve
        className="org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve" />
</Context>
```

In my `web.xml` file I've added a `login-config` and `security-role`:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>KEYCLOAK</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
</security-role>
```

I've also added my `keycloak.json` file to my `/WEB-INF` directory within the WAR file.  Now I'm trying to test it by adding a `@RolesAllowed` annotation to a test Servlet I've created:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/TestServlet" })
@RolesAllowed({ "roleA", "roleB", "roleXXX" })
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

   ...

}
```

I am not authenticated at this point, so I would expect that hitting `/TestServlet` would cause me to receive a 403 or 401.  However, Tomcat lets me in just fine.  No errors or anything.  As a sanity check, I changed the `@RolesAllowed` annotation to `@DenyAll`, expecting that I would be prevented from hitting the servlet in my browser.  Even after this change I'm still able to get through.

Does anyone have any idea why this is not working as expected?  Is `@RolesAllowed` not supported for Servlets?  I was under the impression that it was.  If not, is there something different I should be doing to integrate Keycloak and Tomcat 9?

Comment: In Wildfly this is part of `wildfly-ejb3-18.0.1.Final.jar` and Tomcat doesn't support EJB's by default.  What jar are you including to get it to even compile?  It's not in the Keycloak Tomcat adapter.

Comment: I've added Weld to my app for CDI support.  It's coming from weld-servlet-shaded-3.1.2.Final.jar